# PHP-generated checkbox value

Tags: php, checkbox

I'm using the following code to generate a table with 3 columns.  Lets focus on the 2nd one.  It's a checkbox, who's value should be set to the $file variable (which is part of a foreach of $files which comes from dirscan).

```
<form action="download.php" method="post">
    <tr>
        <td class="tabheader" colspan="3"> HEADER </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>SUBHEAD1</td>
        <td>SUBHEAD2</td>
        <td>SUBHEAD3</td>
    </tr>
    <!-- PHP to add Current dirscan -->
    <?php 
    $files = scandir('./PATH_TO_FILES');
    $origGempath = "http://www.domain.com/beta/";
    $rowcell1 = "<tr><td>LIS</td>";
    $rowcell2 = "<td><input type='checkbox' name='GEMin[]' value='{$file}' /></td>";
    $rowbegin = "$rowcell1" . "$rowcell2";
    $rowend = "</td></tr>";
    unset($files{0},$files{1}); 
    foreach($files as $file) {
        echo $rowbegin;
        echo "<td>";
        echo "<a href='$origGempath/$file'";
        echo "</a>" . $file . $rowend; } 
    ?> 
    <tr><td class="tabenddown" colspan="3"><input type="submit" value="Download"> </td></tr>
</form></table>
```

--

Everything seems to look right graphically, but the checkboxes value's come out blank. (when debugging HTML, it shows value="".

Any ideas?

Comment: `$file` is out of scope there

Comment: Got it.  Any suggestions to get it to work?

Comment: @Daniel learn PHP basics about how variables and string handling works, specifically about scope. The PHP site is a good place to start: http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At the point you are using the variable `$file` it isn't set. Set the `$rowbegin` variable inside the `foreach`:

```
$rowend = "</td></tr>";
unset($files{0},$files{1}); 
foreach($files as $file) {
    $rowcell2 = "<td><input type='checkbox' name='GEMin[]' value='{$file}' /></td>";
    $rowbegin = "$rowcell1" . "$rowcell2";

    echo $rowbegin;
    ...
}
```

Comment: It's set:    foreach($files as $file)

Comment: Is the problem that I'm setting it in $rowcell2 which is before the foreach?  Even though I don't actually bring it into action until echo $rowbegin

Comment: At the point you are using it, is not set. You cannot put a variable in a string and then later set it.